# Telegram Bot replying late after deployed on Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, telegram-bot

I am a newbie and am experimenting with different tutorials using Langchain and OpenAI. Recently I created a telegram bot and deployed it on azure.
I have experienced delays in the responses there. The log stream sometimes keep showing

```
No new trace in the past n min(s).
```

or sometimes it starts the chain but does not finish it for sometime. It needs to get finished for me to get a response.
And then suddenly, out of nowhere, I start getting responses of all the messages.
This is my code:

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def telegram_webhook():
    json_str = request.get_data().decode('UTF-8')
    update = Update.de_json(json.loads(json_str), bot)
    
    user_id=update.message.chat_id
    user_question = update.message.text.lower()
    if user_id not in user_chat_histories:
        user_chat_histories[user_id] = []  # Initialize chat history for new user
    # Retrieve the user's existing chat history
    chat_history = user_chat_histories[user_id]

    if any(response in user_question for response in Generic_responses):
        bot.reply_to(update.message.chat_id, "We are here to help! Let me know if you need anything else or you can reach us on our website adroittech.eu")
    else:
        bot_response = chatbot_handler(user_question, chat_history)

        if bot_response:
            # Reply with text only
            bot.send_message(update.message.chat_id, bot_response)
        else:
            # Handle empty response
            bot.send_message(update.message.chat_id, "I'm sorry, I couldn't generate a response for your question.")
    
    return jsonify({'status': 'ok'})
```

Recently I also got an error msg on azure bash saying my disk has no space. Could that be a reason as well? Or is it something in the code, I provided? If not, how can I make it work better?

I am extremely new to Azure and followed this for deploying:

https://github.com/daveebbelaar/langchain-experiments/tree/deployment

This is my first time using Azure or any cloud service. I'd greatly appreciate your help. Thanks!